# 14.04 no internet connection when I up the bridge interface (for LXC container)

Tags: networking, 14.04, lxc, network-bridge

I have VM Ubuntu 14.04 32bit running in VMware Workstation on Win 10.

I'm trying to set up the LXC container having its own IP address so I set the bridge interface in /etc/network/interfaces (tried static and dhcp):

```
 # interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
 auto lo   
 iface lo inet loopback 

 auto br0
 iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

But then I reboot it and have no internet on my host mashine Ubuntu.

```
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 1999ms
pipe 3
```

But it can connect to the router and I can ssh it from my main OS (win 10)

my host ifconfig:

```
root@ubuntu:~# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:68:f1:39
          inet addr:192.168.1.4  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe68:f139/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:483 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:180 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:39212 (39.2 KB)  TX bytes:28823 (28.8 KB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:68:f1:39
          inet addr:192.168.1.10  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:488 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:268 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:46338 (46.3 KB)  TX bytes:39955 (39.9 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:128 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:128 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:20434 (20.4 KB)  TX bytes:20434 (20.4 KB)
```

I read all the similar posts but did not help. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late reply, but just started writing in here.

I assume you have installed the bridge-utils via apt-get.

Edit the /etc/network/interfaces file. It should seem similar to this:

```
# Bridge between eth0 and eth1
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
# For static configuration delete or comment out the above line and uncomment the following:
# iface br0 inet static
#  address 192.168.1.10
#  netmask 255.255.255.0
#  gateway 192.168.1.1
#  dns-nameservers 192.168.1.5
#  dns-search example.com
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0
```

So quickly put, give your br0 the values originally handled by the eth0. Your eth0 should not contain any IP-information.

```
ifup br0
```